# Ensure a variables live long enough to store reference to it

Tags: rust, lifetime

rust beginner here.

I'm trying to learn about lifetimes, but can't manage to wrap my head around something :
I want to build a Vec of struct, and populate it by passing it to the struct so it decides if it want to put itself into or not.

Here is an exemple :

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    value: bool,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn add_to_vec(&Self, vec: &Vec<&MyStruct>) {
        if self.value {
            vec.push(&self);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut my_vec: Vec<&MyStruct> = Vec::new();
    //let's say my_structs is a defined array of MyStruct
    for struct in my_structs.iter() {
        struct.add_to_vec(&my_vec);
    }
}
```

This code does not compile, because we are not assured that the structs that are referenced in the vec will live longer than the vec itself, thus creating dangling pointers.

How could I use lifetimes (or anything else) to make this work ?

Comment: Do you need to store references? The conventional solution in most cases would be to store *values*. If you store references, then yes, you need to use lifetime annotations.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to match the lifetimes, meaning that the vector should store references that live at least as `'self`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    value: bool,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn add_to_vec<'s>(&'s self, vec: &mut Vec<&'s MyStruct>) {
        if self.value {
            vec.push(self);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut my_vec: Vec<&MyStruct> = Vec::new();
    let my_struct = MyStruct {value: true};
    let my_struct2 = MyStruct {value: true};
    let my_structs = [&my_struct, &my_struct2];
    for s in my_structs.iter() {
        s.add_to_vec(&mut my_vec);
    }
    println!("{my_vec:?}");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=16d9b2b67b3b0dc661eb8d5b51dfb99f)